# Is 28 the only number with this property?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

28 can be written both as the sum of a positive cube plus one and as $2^n-4$. Is the only integer with this property?

Comment: Arithmetically, it might be easier to focus on $27$ which is both a cube and $2^n-5$, or $32$ which is both $n^3+5$ and a power of $2$, and ask whether they are alone with their respective properties.

Comment: $0$ is also such an integer.

Comment: Excluding 0 which is trivial

Answer (score 3):

Let $N$ be the number satisfying these two properties. Then $N$ can be written as 
$$N=2^n -4 = m^3+1.$$

We know that cube of any integer is congruent to $0,1,4$ or $7\pmod8$, so reducing above equation mod $8$,  we have:

$$N=2^n -4 = 1 \pmod 8$$
or $$N=2^n -4 = 2 \pmod 8$$
or $$N=2^n -4 = 5 \pmod 8$$
or $$N=2^n -4 = 0 \pmod 8$$

Since $2^n-4$ is always even, the first and third cases are not possible. The second case leads to:
$$N=2^n -4 = 2 \pmod 8 \implies 2^n = 6 \pmod 8$$ which is not possible.
The last case leads to: $$N=2^n -4 = 0 \pmod 8 \implies 2^n = 4 \pmod 8 \implies n=2.$$ 
Therefore, there are no more solutions other than $0$ and $28$.

Comment: $2^n-4$ may be odd - but obly for $n=0$, and $-3$ is not a cube plus one.

Comment: Yes, I had that case in my mind.

Comment: This solution is unfortunately completely wrong. The residues of cubes modulo 8 are in fact 0,1,3,5,7. Thus $a^3+5$ is divisible by 8 whenever $a\equiv 3 \pmod 8$. E.g., the solution itself is obtained from $3^3+5=32$, which is divisible by 8. Please delete the answer, this problem is more complicated, it cannot be solved by a simple divisibility argument.

Comment: Ah sorry! I made a mistake. Indeed, if $a \equiv 3 \pmod 8$ then $a^3 \equiv 3 \pmod 8.$ Thanks for pointing out. I will delete my answer.

Before that, please tell me how do you conclude that this problem cannot be solved by simple divisibility argument.

Comment: @SARTHAKGUPTA In the case of $28$, the power of $2$ in question is $2^5$. Modulo $8$ cannot differentiate between any of $2^3, 2^4,2^5, $ and so on, so since $2^5$ works, modulo $8$ can't say that there are no more. If there truly are no more examples, then _maybe_ modulo $64$ can show us this, but I don't know what all the cubes look like there, and I suspect that it won't work..